# Ajax to .ashx not returning data

Tags: c#, ajax, generic-handler

The ajax

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Modules/ProductInfo/ProductInfo.ashx',
            data: {
                ProdUID: self.ProductUID()
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            succes: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        })
```

And the `.ashx`

```
partial class ProductInfo : System.Web.UI.Page {
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
         //some code
         Context.Response.Write(
                    Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                        new
                        {
                            html = _html,
                            css = _css,
                            js = _js
                        }
                    )
                );
     }
}
```

The problem is that in my success function i get nothing? Where i do wrong? And also, is there a `class` that i can pass `html, css, js` strings and to render full html page?

Comment: I think you might have a typo in the definition for your SUCCESS function. It's missing the last 's'.